# Return value of a 'boolean' in C

Tags: c, boolean

Which of the following return types is the correct one for the following equality check? Why?

```
int foo1(short x) {
    return x<0;
}

short foo2(short x) {
    return x<0;
}

char foo3(short x) {
    return x<0;
}

#include <stdbool.h>
bool foo4(short x) {
    return x<0;
}
```

Comment: Embrace C99 and go `bool`.

Comment: `x<0` is a relational test, not an equality test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of them will work the same. Integers automatically get converted to booleans and back in C.

However, the *intent* of the code is most clear if you use the `bool` type from `stdbool.h`.

In code that dates back before the 1999 version of standard added `stdbool.h`, there is often a `BOOL` type defined in some header. This pattern shouldn't really be used for new projects, but it makes sense to keep the same style in old projects.